# Coordinator layout TextInput below FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Halloo guys I have problem here with coordinator layout. **I have TextInputLayout and inside it I have editText.** What I want is to show it on click on FAB on the left side and hide on click on FAB.

But I have always problem with edit text going below FAB:
[image: But I have always problem with edit text going below FAB]

Only way I was able to somehow do it is with using `marginRight`, see xml below. But is there any way to do it without that I think there must be better way.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_normal_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_normal_size"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_normal_size">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="banany"
        android:text="testestes....." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAB is always over UI [by design](https://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html):

> Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted
> action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating **above the UI**
> and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and
> the transferring anchor point.

I haven't checked how it is implemented so unless someone else come with better answer you can either check `CoordinatorLayout` and FAB sources to see what makes it hoovering over UI, or if time is short you simply put something **that looks like FAB** (either you use regular button with proper drawable, or 3rd party lib).

Comment: I understand that it has to be above text but I want to achieve showing it on left side of FAB without using margin.

Answer (score -1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="left|center_vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_txt"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="banany"
        android:text="testestes....." />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Just try the above code, hope it suffice the purpose to some extent