# How can I do to display TextInputLayout EditText when clicking FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've wasted hours trying to make it work and I can not do it!

I created a project from scratch in Android Studio with "Navigation drawer"

When the user clicks on the `FloatingActionButton`, I need to show a text box as this image below and when I click on the `FloatingActionButton` again to send the text to my service.

Here the image
[image]

My app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.brazmob.walltoo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:text="TEXTTTTTTTTTT"
            android:id="@+id/busca"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java

```
  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        //TextDrawable trxtDrawable = new TextDrawable("AB");
        //fab.setImageDrawable(trxtDrawable);

        textinput = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textinput);
        busca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busca);

        textinput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        busca.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textinput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                busca.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **id** for your edittext`TextInputLayout`

```
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fab.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                textinput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                busca.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did according to your orientation, but the text box still does not appear

Comment: `textinput = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textinput);
        busca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busca);

        textinput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        busca.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            public void onClick(View view) {
                textinput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                busca.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` I did both with the TextInputLayout and TextEdit and nothing

Comment: That way only the FloatingActionButton fab disappears. Still does not display the text box

Comment: @Will IN your **XML design** there is no Text Box bro

Comment: <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:text="TEXTTTTTTTTTT"
            android:id="@+id/busca"

Comment: This image of the comment is the design that is in the post is how it should stay. I have not solved it yet. Why do I need to use CoordinatorLayout I can not switch to RelativeLayout

Comment: Same problem as my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121028/coordinator-layout-textinput-below-floatingactionbutton